# .call(this) triggering String.prototype.replaceAll from unrelated function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Below I have shown two scripts and I would like to understand why the second script is triggered by the first script. The second script fails because an unescaped "[" is passed to new RegExp(search, 'g'). The failure in the second script causes the first script to also stop.

I understand why this fails, but I don't understand why the second script is triggered?

Is there any way to fix this? I do not have access to the second script but could change the first script.

**Here's what's happening:**

1. evaluate(expression) is called
2. cleanExpression.replaceAll("[",""); runs and triggers the second script. Not sure why?
3. function(search, replacement) is triggered ?
4. return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement); fails causing evaluate function to also fail

**First script**

```
class CustomProduct extends HTMLElement {

  evaluate(expression) {

    let cleanExpression = expression;
    cleanExpression = cleanExpression.replaceAll("[","");
    return math.evaluate(cleanExpression)
  }

}
```

**Second Script**

```
function SocialLoginNamespace() {

(function() {

    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
    };

}).call(this);

var socialLogin = new SocialLoginNamespace().socialLogin;
socialLogin.init();
```

**The error:**

```
resource.js?shop=ccc.myshopify.com&cache_key=1650344:1241 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[/: Unterminated character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at SocialLoginNamespace.String.replaceAll (resource.js?shop=ccc.myshopify.com&cache_key=1650344:1241:31)
    at CustomProduct.evaluate (global.js:7956:39)
    at CustomProduct.evaluateFormula (global.js:7017:43)
    at async CustomProduct.textSelecting (global.js:5935:31)
    at async HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (global.js:8564:9)
```

So why is

```
  cleanExpression = cleanExpression.replaceAll("[","");
```

triggering the function in the second script ?

Comment: Because you're modifying `String.prototype.replaceAll`, so any call to `someString.replaceAll(...)` will call the function you've assigned in the second snippet

Comment: So is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Seems like modifying String.prototype.replaceAll as you say would be a bad idea in general because of exactly this type of problem.  Would it be true to say that or should the first function be changed in some way?

I don't have control of the second script but it seems like this type of script could cause all sorts of problems with many other scripts.

Comment: Yeah, modifying the prototype can lead to all sorts of problems, it's not very good practice so it's ashame you can't modify the 2nd script. You can try and preserve the original `replaceAll()` function by saving it in a variable before your second script runs and use that in your 1st script. Otherwise, you can use a regular `.replace()` in your 1st script instead of `.replaceAll()` : `.replace(/\[/g, '')`. You can also try modifying your 1st script to escape the character class character`[`, eg: `.replaceAll("\\[", "")`